# C string from GetString() when strlen produces segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, strlen, cs50

I am running a program in C. When I run the program I get a segmentation fault error. IN gdb when I backtrace it tells me

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   __strlen_sse2_bsf () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen-sse2-bsf.S:51 51        movdqu  (%edi),
>   %xmm1

I believe it has to do with strlen.

The only time I use strlen is:

```
    string s = GetString();

    int stringlength = strlen(s);
```

When I change strlen for sizeof error stops.

What is wrong with my code?

Documentation of GetString

```
/*
 * Reads a line of text from standard input and returns it as a 
 * string (char *), sans trailing newline character.  (Ergo, if
 * user inputs only "\n", returns "" not NULL.)  Returns NULL
 * upon error or no input whatsoever (i.e., just EOF).  Leading
 * and trailing whitespace is not ignored.  Stores string on heap
 * (via malloc); memory must be freed by caller to avoid leak.
 */

string GetString(void) {
    // growable buffer for chars
    string buffer = NULL;

    // capacity of buffer
    unsigned int capacity = 0;

    // number of chars actually in buffer
    unsigned int n = 0;

    // character read or EOF
    int c;

    // iteratively get chars from standard input
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        // grow buffer if necessary
        if (n + 1 > capacity)
        {
            // determine new capacity: start at 32 then double
            if (capacity == 0)
                capacity = 32;
            else if (capacity <= (UINT_MAX / 2))
                capacity *= 2;
            else
            {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
            }

            // extend buffer's capacity
            string temp = realloc(buffer, capacity * sizeof(char));
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
            }
            buffer = temp;
        }

        // append current character to buffer
        buffer[n++] = c;
    }

    // return NULL if user provided no input
    if (n == 0 && c == EOF)
        return NULL;

    // minimize buffer
    string minimal = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(minimal, buffer, n);
    free(buffer);

    // terminate string
    minimal[n] = '\0';

    // return string
    return minimal;
}
```

Comment: What does `GetString` do? I'm guessing you didn't null terminate your string...

Comment: what is ``string``? ``std::string`` or ``char *``?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I assume it returns a C string. Your problem, then, is string is a C++ type, whereas strlen requires a null-terminated array of characters.

Comment: You've not given us enough information to be definitive.  What is the type `string`?  Is it a C++ `std::string` or a C `typedef char *string;` or something else?  What does `GetString()` do?  I'd guess you got NULL pointer back form `GetString()` and `strlen()` crashed because of that.

Comment: Is this C or C++? If it's C, then how is `string` defined? If C++, is it `std::string`, or something else? And if it's `std::string`, how does `strlen(s)` even compile? And more importantly, what does `GetString` actually return?

Comment: @duskast: what makes you think this is a C++ question rather than a C question as the OP tagged it?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion; someone changed the language tag for some reason. But we still need to know what `GetString` does, since your code snippet implies that it's not returning a valid null-terminated string.

Comment: It is C language. the GetString() is a function given to me by the school. I am a beginner of this language. when you ask what type of string? the variable type I was given to create program is that it is a "string." Assuming that the problem is that there is no null terminator in the string that GetString returns for me, how could I add the terminator to the string?

Comment: @IberoMedia: Did your school give you documentation for what `GetString` does? In particular, are there situations in which it can return `NULL` or some other invalid string? (`string` isn't a standard C type, but I guess that `string` is an alias for `char*`, otherwise the call to `strlen` wouldn't compile). As it is, I don't think the question can be answered here; try using the debugger to look higher up the backtrace, and check the values of all the pointers being used.

Comment: Many of the questions that people have asked would have been answered by a minimal, <strong>compilable</strong> testcase. By not including a testcase, *you're making us ask for help* rather than asking for help, yourself; We have to ask *what is this?* and *what is that?*. Ask for help the correct way, or we can't help you!

Comment: As I mentioned before I am a beginner of this language. When I posted the question I did not know that GetString was not part of stdio.h  If you expect perfect questions from likely stackoverflow audience, in this case moi, perhaps the website would not be necessary. I don't know what compilable testcase is.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, my bad. The question in the very beginning didn't contain the GetString definition so I mistook `string` as `std::string` (well, this can't even compile, I should have been more careful when retagging)

Comment: @IberoMedia: "Compilable testcase" means enough code is given that we can build an executable and run it ourselves, without us having to write extra code (and making possibly invalid assumptions in the process).

Comment: @MatthewD thank you, you both are right. I too wish I could formulate my questions better. I am working on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The description of the `getString()` function clearly states that it can return NULL on an error or on EOF.

If you pass the return value to `strlen()` without checking, your program will crash.

```
string s = GetString();
int stringlength = 0;

if (s != 0)
    stringlength = strlen(s);
```

This at least won't crash.

You might also notice how much confusion the `typedef char *string;` causes and how little benefit it confers, and take it to heart.  You don't have to repeat the mistakes of those who are teaching you.

I also observe that the code fragment:

```
// minimize buffer
string minimal = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char));
strncpy(minimal, buffer, n);
free(buffer);
```

could be better, and more simply, written as:

```
string minimal = realloc(buffer, n + 1);
```

to shrink the allocation to the correct size.

Comment: thank you, the check string for null before I use strlen solved my problem. Thank you