# How do I fix error "use of undeclared identifier n" in C?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error, undeclared-identifier, cs50

I'm sure there are probably tons of syntax/other errors, but I'm trying to figure out the two that it's picking up on.  I'm very new to this so I don't really know how to fix undeclared identifiers. Note that `#include <cs50.h>` is just CS50's library.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{ 
   int add, fee, disc;
   printf("For rate with tax and Security Deposit, type y. For 10 percent off, type n:"); 
   string name = GetString();
   if (name == y)
   { 
     printf("PreTax Amount: ");
     scanf("%d", &fee);
     printf("Okay. I will add the 10 percent tax to %d.\n ", fee);

     add        = (1.1 * fee);

     printf("Plus Tax Amount = %d\n", add);
     printf("Security Deposit = 1000 dollars\n");
     printf("Total = (%d + 1000)", add); 
   }  
   else if (name == n)
   {
     printf("PreTax Amount: ");
     scanf("%d%d", &fee, &disc);
     printf("Okay. I will minus the 10 percent discount to %d and then add tax.\n ", fee);

     add        = (0.9 * fee);
     disc       = (add * 1.1);

     printf("Minus Discount Amount plus tax = %d\n", disc);
     printf("Security Deposit = 1000 dollars\n");
     printf("Total = (%d + 1000)", disc);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

errors:

```
ContractualHelper.c:10:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'y'
if (name == y)
            ^
ContractualHelper.c:22:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
else if (name == n)
                 ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: The compiler is saying "I don't know what's `y`."

Comment: The same error twice: you want to compare against the literal character `'n'` or the literal string `"n"`, not "a *variable* called `n`". Names of variables don't mean anything to running code; C is not introspective.

Answer (score 1):

`y` and `n` are undeclared because they do not have definitions.

`int y;` is a declaration, which would get rid of that error.

However, your code

```
if (name == y)
```

is comparing a variable `name` to a variable `y`, and I think what you want to do is see if `name` contains the string `y`.

How to do that comparison is another issue.

Comment: hint: strcmp, strncmp (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/), or operator[]

Comment: @PeterSchneider So does strcmp ask "What is contained in variable 'name'"? thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Strcmp takes arguments of two strings, and tells you if they are the same. You can send those in as variables.

Comment: @cb61899:  Did you read the man page I linked to? Which part is it that you didn't understand (I'm not being sarcastic)? Do you understand what C "strings" are at all? Btw, I realize that you use a GetString() function with a type string which is not part of standard C; is it the same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892003/c-string-from-getstring-when-strlen-produces-segmentation-fault ? Then my somewhat flippant pointers to st[n]cmp are valid (because `string` appears to be just a typedef for `char *`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want just to compare with either 'Y' or 'N' I suggest you use `char` instead of `string`.
so :
`char name;`

`scanf("%c", &name);`

than when comparing use :

`if (name == 'Y') ...`

**ADD**

you also should consider wrong inputs from user so add another `else` like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   char name;
   scanf("%c", &name);

   if (name == 'y') 
    printf("Yes");

   else if (name == 'n')
    printf("No");

   else 
        printf("wrong input");
}
```

Comment: Using `string` makes the input process a lot simpler, he doesn't have to worry about newlines left in the input stream and other such guff

Comment: Yes sure, but you could just follow his path and deduce that he wants a one over two possible flows "yes or no", i guess it's for class assignment

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) I'm actually just using cs50's VMWare to make this for the contracts I write up for my mom's vacation rental business. It's not an actual class project, so no plagiarism rules apply.

Comment: @cb61899 Respect for u mate, i wish my mom appreciates me doing some programming for her also ;) anyway no worry we are in programming QA site there is no plagiarism risk